# iPhone 4 needs to restored, but I am concerned about losing photos

Tags: ios, iphone, restore, data-recovery

My iPhone 4 suddenly turned off and won't turn back on. I've tried charging it, holding the home and top button and plugging it into my computer. Nothing is working. When I plugged it into my computer, I received a notification that the phone is in recovery mode and needs to be restored to factory settings. I am fine with restoring it, but my concern is that I haven't backed up my phone for awhile and I don't want to lose the photos that were taken after the last time I backed up the device.

Is there anything I can do to restore the phone and still manage to save my pictures?

Comment: As far as I know there is not much you can do, but maybe someone has a glorious idea that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two apps that will mount your iPhone as a USB drive. One is Called "[Phone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/)" the other is called iExplorer. If you google for them you can download one. Simply plug your phone into your computer. When iTunes comes up, hit cancel, and then browse your iPhone just like you would in the finder. Drag the "Photos" folder onto your computer.

All backed up!

Another app, called [WiFi Photos](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-photo-transfer/id380326191?mt=8) (free), goes on your phone, when you launch it any mac on the same wifi can go to a special URL, and browse your iPhone photos and right click to save!